# local.xml Url Helper for skin/images folder

Tags: url, local.xml, helper

I have added a top.link and want to include an image inside the label. I'm not sure how to get the current_skin/images folder from within my local.xml though.

This is what I have so far

```
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
            <label><![CDATA[<img src="current_skin/images/image.svg">]]> Klantenservice</label>
            <url>klantenservice</url>
            <title>Klantenservice</title>
        </action>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by following method

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="yourmodule">
    <label helper="yourmodule/yourfunction"/>
    <url>klantenservice</url>
    <title>Klantenservice</title>
</action>
```

And in your module helper file ([To create custom module refer this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table))

```
app/code/local/{namespace}/{module}/Helper/Data.php
```

Write a function to get the label dynamically.

```
public function yourfunction()
{
   return "<img src='".Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('images/logo.gif')."'/>".$this->__('Klantenservice');
}
```